# karma test suite empty from Chrome

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have a problem with setting up units tests in project. When I run tests with IE everything works fine I can see 4/4 tests executed. With chrome i am getting error Empty test suite. Chrome is launched but it looks like it can;t find tests and tests for chrome are not executed.

Karma.config.js

```
    module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-ie-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

test.ts is just searching unittests within app folder:

```
 .then(() => require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was with reporters section, after 2 days of agony I changed file to

```
      reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
        ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
        : ['progress'],
```

removed mime section and  it works!